# How can I log the JSON data sent by Spring RestTemplate + ApacheHttpClient + Jackson?

Tags: log4j, jackson, apache-httpclient-4.x, resttemplate

I'm using RestTemplate from Spring v4 to send http requests. RestTemplate uses Apache HttpClient v4 under the hood and I'm using Jackson v2 for pojo-json conversion.

I have Log4J working. How can I configure log4j.properties to show the sent json data in the logs?

Enabling these loggers in "FINEST" level didn't help:

- org.springframework.http
- org.apache.http
- org.apache.commons.httpclient
- httpclient
- org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jackson

I'd prefer doing it via log4j.properties than coding some sort of interceptor (which I'll want to keep only in dev). But do let me know of other ways.

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you. The question implies that you have logging working. If that's the case just create an instance of a configured logger and then call the info method to log your JSON object (like you would log anything else).  Maybe your real question is "how do I log stuff with Log4j?"

Comment: @mbmast I don't have access to the generated json anywhere in my application's code. I see only java objects. Spring calls jackson at some point to generate the json.

Comment: You've got to be close ... Check this for additional https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html

Comment: At first I thought maybe Jackson could be configured in some way to first call your code. You would then delegate to Jackson and log the resulting JSON. This can be done if you're making the calls to Jackson but you're not; Spring is.  And there appears to be no config file that Jackson reads. See http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers.  You could write your own class with the same method signature that Spring is calling and put it in a jar in the class path before the Jackson jar. You'd have to do your own class loading in order to delegate to the real Jackson though.